# List<T> is not equal to List<T>?

Tags: java, generics

Have a look at this simple example of Java generics:

```
class List<T> {
    T head;
    List<T> next;
}

class A<T> {
    List<T> l;

    public <T> int length() {
        List<T> l = this.l;
        int c = 1;
        while (l.next != null) {
            c++;
            l = l.next;
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A<Integer> a = new A<Integer>();
        a.l = new List<Integer>();
        a.l.head = 123;
        a.l.next = new List<Integer>();
        a.l.next.head = 432;
        System.out.println("list length: " + a.length());
    }
}
```

It gets an error compiling, claiming that the types are incompatible, yet claiming that the two variables are the same type:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:10: incompatible types
found   : List<T>
required: List<T>
        List<T> l = this.l;
                        ^
1 error
```

If I change the first line of length() to `List<T> l = (List<T>)(Object)this.l;`, it works. Why?

Comment: Creating a class whose name conflicts with such a common JDK class (`java.util.List` in this case) is a bad idea. Confusion will abound.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've declared a generic method inside a generic class with this line:

```
public <T> int length() {
```

This `<T>` is different than your class's `<T>`.  According to the [JLS Section 6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a class's type parameter (§8.1.2) is the type parameter
>   section of the class declaration, the type parameter section of any
>   superclass or superinterface of the class declaration, and the class
>   body.

You don't need to re-declare `<T>` on your method; the class's type parameter is already in scope.

To use your class's generic type parameter `<T>`, have your method not declare another `<T>` and simply use your class's `<T>`:

```
public int length() {
```

To understand why your casting works:

```
List<T> l = (List<T>)(Object)this.l;
```

You can cast any object to `Object`.  Then you are casting the result to `List<T>`.  You can always cast it to anything you want; Java will simply throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime if it wasn't really a `List` at runtime.  But the compiler will also give a warning that it uses unchecked or unsafe operations, because it can't guarantee that this `<T>` is the original `<T>`.

To illustrate the difference between `<T>`s, you can use `<U>` as the generic type parameter for the method and get the same results:

```
public <U> int length() {
    List<U> l = (List<U>)(Object)this.l;
```

This compiles with the same type safety warning.

If you really know that type safety can be guaranteed, you can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to annotate your method.  But here, I'd still go with removing the generic type parameter from the method entirely, and using the class's type parameter.